# React Router 4 - accessing child params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to get access to the params (e.g. match.params) for a child component.  For example:

```
const Vets = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <LeftMenu vetId={match.params.vetId} catId=??? />
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${match.path}/cats/:catId`} component={Cat} />
        <Route path={`${match.path}/dogs/:dogId`} component={Dog} />
      </Switch> 
    </div>
    <RightActionBar /> (<- uses withRouter to get vetId.  Would like to get catId)
  </div>
)
```

URL: myapp.com/vets/12/cats/194

In the Vet component I can access match.params and get any params that were in the section of the URL that matched in the parent to present this component (such as vetId, but not catId).  Also, if I use withRouter in the RightActionBar component, I can get the same match.params, BUT NOT THE CAT OR DOG ID.

In the Cat and Dog components, I can access props.match.params and get the params available above AND THE CAT OR DOG ID.

Lets say I want to know the cat or dog id in the LeftMenu or RightActionBar component.  How would I access it?

As far as I can tell, this was doable in earlier versions through props.params, but not any more.  I know I could use the location prop and write my own function to work it out, but my app is a little more complex than the example and I'm hoping theres a more elegant solution out of the box that I've missed.

Comment: are <LeftMenu /> and <RightActionBar /> IDs you want in <Cat /> and <Dog /> accessible in the above snippet?

Comment: @Tony - sorry no, what I want is the other way around.  I've modified the question to try to clarify

Comment: In case you didn't realize if you move the route definition up then you have access to the dogId and catId params.  You would have those 2 path definitions in the switch both Route to the Vets component, and then in Vets you would have access to match.params.catId and match.params.dogId.  Then rather than a switch you would do something like `if (dogId) { <Dog /> } else { <Cat /> }`

Comment: Thanks @brub, I did know I could do that, but was hoping to avoid it, as in my real app there is a lot more routes in the switch in the Vets component, and then some of the components presented by that switch also have nested routes for which I'll want access to their params too.

Comment: @MorganDangerHall How did you end up with this?

Comment: @HaykSafaryan - have posted my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating a component that rendered my LeftMenu and RightActionBar:

```
const Wrapper = ({ animalType , match: { params: { animalId, vetId }}}) => (
  <>
    <LeftMenu animalId={animalId} animalType={animalType} vetId={vetId} />
      {children}
    <RightActionBar vetId={vetId} /> 
  </>
)
```

Then I used the router `render` method instead of `component`:

```
const Vets = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route 
        path={`${match.path}/cats/:animalId`} 
        render={(props) => (
          <Wrapper animalType={'cat'} {...props}>
            <Cat catId={props.match.params.animalId} />
          </Wrapper>
         )}
      </Route>
      <Route 
        path={`${match.path}/dogs/:animalId`} 
        render={(props) => (
          <Wrapper animalType={'cat'} {...props}>
            <Dog dogId={props.match.params.animalId} />
          </Wrapper>
         )}
      </Route>
    </Switch> 
  </div>
)
```

I could also have just added the `<Wrapper/>` component to the outer layer of the `<Cat/>` and `<Dog/>` renders instead, but I wanted to keep them  clean so I could use them without it elsewhere